# Upload file to share point server from external application

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

My client has requested to upload files to his share point server from and external application. So I have designed a windows application and used Microsoft.sharepoint.dll supplied by client and used the following code for upload.

```
 Public Function UploadFileToSharepoint(ByVal pstrSourceFilePath As String, ByVal pstrTargeSPURL As String) As Boolean

    If Not File.Exists(pstrSourceFilePath) Then

        Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} does not exist", pstrSourceFilePath), "srcUrl")

    End If

    Dim site As SPWeb = New SPSite(pstrTargeSPURL).OpenWeb()

    Dim fStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(pstrSourceFilePath)
    Dim contents(CInt(fStream.Length)) As Byte
    fStream.Read(contents, 0, CInt(fStream.Length))
    fStream.Close()

    EnsureParentFolder(site, pstrTargeSPURL)

    site.Files.Add(pstrTargeSPURL, contents)

    Return True
End Function
```

I am able to compile it but while running the application I am getting an error like "Could not load or found an assembly "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Library.dll".

My question: Is it possible to develop an application to create a folder structure and upload the file to share point server without having the share point installed on the machine but having only the share point dll's?

Suggest me a way to carry out this kind of development. In future my application will run on  a machine where share point server is not installed.

Rupesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using Client Object Model - just reference Microsoft.SharePoint.Client in your project. Here's how to do it in C#, VB.net shouldn't be much different.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://mydomain");
Web web = context.Web;
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\MyFile.docx");
newFile.Url = "MyFile.docx"; 
List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the SharePoint Client-Side Object model (CSOM). That will allow you to interact with SharePoint from a client.

More info here --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535451(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1